# Significance of Lamentations postscript

Tags: lamentations

What is the meaning and translation of the postscript at the end of the book of Lamentations and was this included in the original autograph?

Comment: Please provide a reference.  The original autographs have long been lost.

Comment: are you referring to the letter of Baruch? If so, which Bible includes it as a postscript to Lamentations? Usually it's a separate book, considered canonical by Catholics but not included in most Protestant bibles.

Comment: I opened this question again managing to include a .jpg of the text in question in the Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia.